# How to exploit RSA and DHE export?

Tags: cryptography, man-in-the-middle, rsa

I'm a white-hat beginner and I found two sites on Censys which have DHE and RSA exports. How can I show that these sites are not secure and are vulnerable to attack?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go ahead and so much as "show," but rather inform. Find the contact information for their System Administrator and/or security team, and inform them of what you've found, and how you believe it could be used as a vulnerability.

"Doing" anything to "show" a vulnerability, i.e. hacking, regardless of intentions good or bad, is still considered illegal without consent from the individual or organization.